# Need to move file from one folder to another

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBS. I need help to do the following steps;

1) Find the lastest modified folder(folder with latest date time) at a location lets say C:\temp.

2) Then find the specific file (with extention .txt) in the subfolder (of the above mentioned folder)

3) Copy that file to another location, lets assume C:\temp1

4) Rename the file name to current date, for example 2011-02-14

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript:

```
BaseDir = "C:\Temp"
FileToFind = "test.txt"

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fl = fs.GetFolder(BaseDir)

For Each sfl In fl.SubFolders
    If IsNull(fd) Or sfl.DateCreated > fd Then
        fd = sfl.DateCreated
        Found = sfl.Path & "\"
    End If
Next

Set f = fs.GetFile(Found & FileToFind)

f.Copy "C:\Temp1\" & Year(Date) & Month(Date) & Day(Date), True
```

There may be problems including "-" in the file name, so I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some psuedo code how you would do it in bash on Windows (with cygwin)

```
# change to the directory so we can avoid path issues
cd /path/to/temp

# get the most recently modified directory
myDirectory = "`ls -drt */ | tail -n1`"

# change to that directory
cd "$myDirectory"

# Here you can use cp or mv depending if you want to remove the file from orig   
directory
cp "specificFile.txt" "/path/to/temp1/`date command with flags`.txt"
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply and help but i am sorry this is above my head. I am specifically looking for VB script help.

Comment: It seems odd to post bash as an answer to a question tagged vbscript.